# Adding facebook like to the posts with font awesome

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I need to add facebook like button with "font awesome" to every post's sidebar, like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWvex.jpg]

Tried this option https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button but it seems unstyleable.

I need something like

`<a src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>`

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:-

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

Building the links yourself this way gives you a couple of advantages. One, you can style them how you want; and two, you aren't reliant on third-party resources that may/will slow your pages performance.

Here's a full list of [social media bookmarking links](http://andy-carter.com/blog/social-media-bookmarking-links) that you can use to build fully customisable links.